# Angular service-worker prefetching video file

Tags: javascript, angular, request, html5-video, service-worker

When there is a video embed on the page, the service worker **prefetches** the whole video, which causes performance issues. In my **ngsw-config.json**, there are only configs for local files, but the video is located on different subdomain under */sites/default/files/video/* folder structure.

How can i exclude all the file requests from prefetching? I want to prefetch only the files/urls, i described in my **ngsw-config.json**.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://some.external.url.com/sites/default/files/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons",
          "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v50/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this with extending the default ngsw-worker.js file.

1. I copied the `ngws-worker.js` from the build to the project `src` folder
2. Renamed it to `custom-ngsw-worker.js`
3. Added the .mp4 regex match to `onFetch(event)` method
4. Added this .js file to `angular.json` assets
5. Registered it in the `app.module.ts` instead of the original `ngsw-worker.js`

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
...
ServiceWorkerModule.register('custom-ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' }),
...
]
```

**custom-ngsw-worker.js**

```
onFetch(event) {

...

// Skip video files
if (req.url.match('^.*(\.mp4).*$')
) {
  return;
}

...
```

This way it ignores all .mp4 files and won't cache them. If there is a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ["lazy" installMode](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#installmode) for that external URL.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.